# Is it possible to split a large Maven project AND still preserve Reactor Sorting, parent pom, etc?

Tags: java, git, maven

I'm trying to split up a large-ish Maven application which lives in a monolithic git repository. The code itself is already modular, but being that all the modules are in one repository, every build takes a long time (how long? too long), every IDE is pushed to its limit when doing checkouts, etc.

The one nice thing about the monolithic repo is that by sharing a common parent POM which is always there, dependency and configuration management is greatly simplified (e.g. everyone gets the same version of Spring, Hibernate, and Jackson) and we get some nice functionality such as Reactor Sorting when rebuilding at the parent pom level, ability to do `mvn versions:set` to bump version numbers globally, all while retaining developer's ability to build just one project at a time.

How can the project be broken up so that these four conditions are met:

1. Every module in its own separate git repo
2. All modules share a common configuration for major dependencies and plugins
3. Global builds follow the correct sequence (as in Reactor Sorting)
4. A developer working on a single module is not greatly inconvenienced

My initial thought was to just copy the contents of the parent pom into each module pom, get rid of the parent pom reference, and check each module into a new repo -- but that only accomplishes conditions #1 and #4 at the cost of #2 and #3.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "inconvenienced".  There is no way round the fact that a multi-repo makes it harder to propagate version changes through a hierarchy of transitive dependencies.  But if your modules have few inter-dependencies, then things may be simpler - you could replace the the dependencies on modules with dependencies dependencies on Maven artifacts.  #2 could be achieved (at questionable friction) by introducing and publishing a "common" artifact/POM.

Comment: Keep the parent POM. You can import dependencies from the parents to their child projects without directly referencing the parent: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies This should solve #2.

Comment: @Compass - What does a parent POM mean in a world where each module is in its own Git repo?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You'd create a new pom for each module of packaging pom, that would import the dependencies of the original parent pom for the version it is targeting. So each git repo now has its own skeletal parent pom that knows how to assemble its contents but takes its imports directly from the original parent pom.

Comment: What does long mean? How many modules do you have ? How many tests do you have? What does this mentioning mean reactor order? The reactor order is defined by the dependencies between modules which implies dependencies between the module and after you split them up between the projects? Is the release cycle for each module different?